# Xamarin.Droid Package creation failed

Tags: xamarin, package, mvvm-light, portable-class-library, xamarin.droid

I chose Build -> Archive for publishing

and I am getting the following error

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2):
>   Error: Could not load assembly ‘myapp, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the
>   Mono for Android profile? (myapp.Droid)

It was working earlier but now not anymore

Comment: Are you able to build normally? If it fails, can you provide a full diagnostic build output?

Comment: I have this problem too, I can build both debug and release but on Archive for publishing it fails. I am also using Visual Studio for Mac

Comment: Let me know if you found the solution

Comment: Have you updated the Xamarin.Forms package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same scenario, the project used to archive but doesn't any longer, same OS, debug is also perfectly fine.

[image]

I found that I only had armeabi-v7a ticked, after ticking x86 it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:**

Change Linker Mode

[image]

**Step2:**

Delete obj & bin files in all platforms

**Step3:**

Rebuild your solution in Debug mode.

**Step4:**

Now put release mode then try maybe it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Release|AnyCPU when building the project instead of Release|ARM. That worked for me.

Comment: Have you copy pasted the Release|ARM configuration to a Release|AnyCPU in a text editor?